# How to adjust rows and columns, retaining cell sizes in arcmap?

Tags: matlab, gis, data-conversion, arcmap

**The Situation**: I have a vector data map with all the countries in the World, including a unique landcode for every country. I need to convert it into a raster map, so I can eventually analyse (with Matlab) drought indicators for that country.

**The Problem**: The precipitation data I use has *720 columns and 360 rows*. I want the raster map of world countries to be in the exact same amount of columns and rows. BUT the raster map also needs to have *a cellsize of 0.5!* Right now, when I use the vector to raster conversion tool, if I use cellsize = 0.5, the columns and rows become *720x287*.

**Question**: How can I create a raster map of 720 columns and 360 rows, while setting cellsize at 0.5?

Thank you in advance!

**Additional info**:
Using ArcMap 10.4.1 and Matlab R2015b

Raster is .TIFF

Vector is .shp

[image: Raster layer properties]

[image: Vector country map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In ArcMap, I imported the precipitation data (NetCDF). It was however flipped, but I could get it in the right orientation using the tools 'Flip' and 'Rotate'. Now this map had the right orientation and the right amount of columns and rows. Furthermore I just altered some of the default settings in environments: 1) I set the processing extent to the precipitation data. 2) I set the snap raster also to the precipitation data. 3) I set the cellsize of every output raster to 0.5. Finally, I converted the vector file of world countries to a ASCII file using the raster to ascii conversion tool. The ASCII file now has the same amount of rows and columns as the precipitation data!

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow GIS user I would recommend posting your question under the GIS stack exchange, https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Beyond that there is some clarification needed.  Are you saying that you are trying to create a multi band raster with 1 band for each column?

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I do still mix up all the  different stackexchange types.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I do still mix up all the  different stackexchange types. 

I need to make a raster of 720 columns and 360 rows based on the unique country administrative codes. This way I can analyse precipitation data for Tanzania (based on its code) in Matlab. It is like clipping: I have precipitation data for the whole world and only want to know how it looks like in Tanzania. 

The raster only has/needs 1 band. Its 'size' is wrong: it is 720x287 instead of 720x360.

Comment: @PolyGeo I did post it on GIS stackexchange, like Dillon_Su suggested. I am not to familliar with the rules yet, should I remove this post?

Comment: @Tristian you won't be able to now because it has an upvoted answer. Instead the takeaway message should be GIS questions to [gis.se], general programming questions to [so] and no questions posted on both.